# Steps to update OpenStreetMap back and forth?

Tags: openstreetmap, import, update, editing

I have both a PostGIS database with OSM data imported, and the same data in a SHP folder.

By adding missing information to the downloaded OSM data, both in SHP and PostGIS, I'd be able to contribute with the project.

If I need to also update my server from an OSM periodical diff, which would be the correct sequence of tasks? (I'm assuming that there is new info in OSM to download and new info on my server to upload, and that would be happening regularly).

Comment: try https://help.openstreetmap.org/ as there many ways to update and receive changes.

Answer (score 0):

update your data from osm and then upload any changes, you could use qgis with a server connection to postgresql containing postgis and then output your shapefile. I believe that would work.